# Unity3D Vectrosity 3.0 Line between GameObject and UI item

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-ui

I'm using Vectrosity to draw a line between my 3D `GameObject` and a `UI` element. However, I'm struggling to convert the `RectTransform` position data so I can pass it to the drawline function.

I've been experimenting with getting the RectTransform position of my desired `UI` elements and trying to draw a line between them. However, this doesn't work. When I change the code to make use of normal 3D objects in my scene, the line appears as intended. This is the code that I currently have been playing with:

```
  void Start ()
{

  //  points[0] = image.rectTransform.transform.position;
  //  points[1] = image2.rectTransform.transform.position;

    points[0] = obj1.transform.position;
    points[1] = obj2.transform.position;

    line = new VectorLine("Line", points, mat, 2.0f, LineType.Continuous);
    VectorLine.canvas.sortingOrder = 1;
    VectorLine.SetCanvasCamera(Camera.main);

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    line.Draw();

}
```

The first commented out line get the positions of my 2 `UI` objects fine, but nothing appears on the screen. The uncommented out line work fine. Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

All of the above is done in a 3D scene. I'll be having my camera orbit, rotate and zoom around the 3D object and would like the line to remain consistent

Comment: updated my original question

Comment: it s'a real pain in the bum to do this .. `RectTransformUtility`  is your friend!

Comment: This is a great question, @Sean - I never have a frickin clue the best way to map from UI to the normal game scene.  It's a great pity there is so much clutter on SO in this tag.  Hopefully your question gets plenty of attention. I will add a bounty once the time passes.